# Check if is a datetime php

Tags: php, datetime

I've made this function

```
function checkNullToInsert($data){

        if($data){
            if($data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')){
                return  "'".$data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'";
            }else{
                return "'".$data."'";
        }
        else {
            return 'NULL'; 
        }
    }
```

And it fails on

> if($data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

but I can see the error (is not my server). 
What changes I have to do to make that function work. If its a datetime, it should return the date ,if not is a datetime returns the data and if its null return a string with 'null' value

Comment: Is `$data` an instance of `DateTme` or is it some other class? And since you say that you can see the error, you _really_ need to include it in the question!

Comment: `$data` its a field of a sql request can be a datetime,int,string..

Comment: You're also missing the closing `}` in the inner if-statement

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is trying to use any value that validates as `truthy` as a `DateTime` instance. Here's the manual about what values are considered true/false: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

First you need to check if the variable *is* an instance of `DateTime`. We can do that with the `instanceof` operator:

```
function checkNullToInsert($data){
    if ($data){
        // Check if the variable is an instance of DateTime.
        if ($data instanceof DateTime) {
            return  "'".$data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'";
        } else {
            return "'".$data."'";
        } // You were also missing this closing brace
    }
    else {
        return 'NULL'; 
    }
}
```

Here's the documentation for `instanceof`: http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.instanceof.php